# PDO query inserts two duplicated rows instead of a single one

Tags: php, pdo

I'm successfully connected to a databse, and a INSERT query using PDO is successfully working. However, it's creating two rows instead of one.

`users` is my database. I can assure you it's connected since i can check the database, and it's creating the rows.

`$db_connection` is the variable that it's pointing to my database e.g.:
`$db_connection = new PDO(mysql:host=`........

It inserts the row successfully, but it's inserting duplicated ones on page load/reload/new tab, whatever.

How can I avoid that? I saw briefly that my browser could be sending two requests? I've tried with different browsers and them all were adding 2 rows instead of one. It's the same on my phone.

What am I missing?

This is my entire code:

(I omitted my database connection details, but just to post here)

```
<?php


$db_host = "";
$db_name = "";
$db_user = "";
$db_pass = "";
$db_syntax = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name";

$db_connection = new PDO($db_syntax, $db_user, $db_pass);

$name="Name Namadooo";
$email="email@email.com";
$password=password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$insert_user="INSERT INTO users (name,email,password,date) VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$date')";
$db_connection->query($insert_user);
?>
```

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even data from the database, [you are still at risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thanks @JasonK, i'll look deeper soon. this is just actually a simple code for personal dev/testing. So i'm trying to find whats the issue/why its creating two rows first.

Comment: By far the most likely reason is that somehow the script is being executed twice. There's nothing _within_ the script you've shown which would cause two rows to be inserted, so I suggest looking at things which trigger the script, instead.

Comment: `it's inserting duplicated ones on page load/reload/new tab, whatever`...well each of those things causes a new request to PHP, so any code in the PHP script you request from the browser will get executed. I presume in reality you'd actually want this to happen as the result of submitting a form? In which case, a) the user is unlikely to do that multiple times (but if they do, it's kinda their fault rather than yours), and b) you can easily write code which checks if the request is actually the result of submitting that form, before trying to do anything.

Comment: It seems to be a general design failure. If you want forbid duplicate entries for the name, then use for e.g. `unique key(name)` for the database field.